# How can extend an internet cable connection using a Wi-Fi range extender?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-extender

**Requirements:**

- One primary router with Wi-Fi ESSID *"Main"*
- One LAN cable
- One Wi-Fi range extender called *"Sitecom N300"* with Wi-Fi ESSID *"Extended"*

**Setup:**

I would like to connect a Wi-Fi range extender through a LAN cable connection to a primary router to extend its *"Main"* Wi-Fi network through a secondary *"Extended"* Wi-Fi network.

Is this technically possible or do Wi-Fi range extenders generally only extend Wi-Fi connections but not LAN cable based connections?

Comment: The Way you are describing it is setting up a new Access point. You could take your Primary router and use the Lan cable to connect to another Router or Repeater and set it up as another access point on a different channel that way your credentials will match and if you roam near the closer AP your device would then connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is put it in "Access Point" mode if it has it. Otherwise you'll need to buy a separate AP.

Answer (score 0):

The following kit would allow you to use powerline technology to create a wifi extender based of a LAN connection:

http://www.ebuyer.com/483192-d-link-dhp-w311av-500mbps-wireless-n-powerline-kit-dhp-w311av-b?gclid=CjwKEAjwubK4BRC1xczKrZyj3mkSJAC6ntgrg3qECe0GXFS_Ukyf4DCE6H0vXg3KoTB0MKp-N-NI1RoChbfw_wcB#fo_c=951&fo_k=c0dc68c34c436527bef5d3b72f786c03&fo_s=gplauk?mkwid=sQBxYqzVY_dc&pcrid=51482427899&pkw=&pmt=

The wired LAN connection exists from the router to the extender (Via the building's electrical circuits). I'm assuming you don't want to just extend using wifi only for speed reasons, correct me if I'm wrong there.

Comment: Dear @Sam3000, thank you for your help! I don't need a powerline kit to extend the connection. I have a sufficiently long cable that goes from my primary router to the Wi-Fi range extender. The only technical challenge that I have is how I can configure the range extender to use the LAN connection as primary input and use this connection for the output signal as Wi-Fi. Is it more clear now?